# a simple sed script displaying only changed lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed

How could I make a separate sed script (let's call it script.sed) that would display only the changed lines without having to use the `-n` option while executing it? (Sorry for my English)

I have a file called data2.txt with digits and I need to change the lines ending with ".5" and print those changed lines out in the console.

I know how to do it with a single command (`sed -n 's/.5$//gp' data2.txt`),  however our university professor requires us to do the same using `sed -f script.sed data2.txt` command.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for your English? It's better than many native English speakers'. In fact, it's immaculate.

Comment: Thank you, you're most kind, I really appreciate that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should work for your sed script:

```
s/.5$//gp
d
```

The `-n` option will suppress automatic printing of the line, the other way to do that is to use the `d` command.  From man page:

> ```
>    d      Delete pattern space.  Start next cycle.
> ```

This works because the automatic printing of the line happens at the end of a cycle, and using the `d` command means you never reach the end of a cycle so no lines are printed automatically.

Comment: As it is anchored to the end of line and it is not a multi-line  expression using a multi-line flag, the `g` is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
#n
s/.5$//p
```

Save this to a file and run as:

```
sed -f file.sed file.txt
```

Comment: first #n is an option equivalent to sed -n set into a sed script ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu see [often-used commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands)

Comment: thank you, didn't know the special behavior of #n at first place in a script